# Locate a web element via sibling in Selenium where the sibling is determined by program

Tags: python, html, selenium, firefox

I need to locate a report link. But the information of the link itself is too general to characterize but its next sibling is a span element whose text can identify the span element. So I decided to first find the span element, then use the span element by the way of preceding-siblings of xpath to find the link element.

I wonder if there is a better way to do it?

Here is the screenshot showing one of such pair of elements:
[image]

Here are the HTML segments showing their definitions and relationship:

```
<td style="font-size: 12px;" width="70%">
    <a href="/reports/4981/"><span><b style="color: #3366FF; text-decoration: underline;">Cases Report</b></span></a>
    <span style="color: #888;">requested on Tue, Mar 20, 2018 at 9:14 p.m. &nbsp;—&nbsp; CSV &nbsp;—&nbsp; <b><i>Ready to download</i></b></span>
</td>
```

Here is my attempted implementation (not fully working yet):

```
span_xpath = '//span[contains(., "Ready to download")]' 
# . stands for text in the current node regardless of in bold or not

relative_report_link_xpath = '//preceding-sibling::a[contains(@href, "/reports/")]'

span_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(span_xpath)
# There might be multiple such links and spans
# I will have logic to select the desired one 
# based on the timestamp in the span. 
# For brevity, I just hard code the selection for now:

found_span = span_list[0] # will be logic involving timestamp
found_span.click() # make the span as the current node

driver.find_element_by_xpath(relative_report_link_xpath).click()
```

For example, I really don't want to click on the span element except for the purpose of making the span as the current node so that I can navigate by preceding-siblings. I wish to know a less "intrusive" implementation of making a web element as the current node without clicking on it. (Clicking on a span element, in this case, maybe OK but if it's part of another link, then the behavior would not be what I want.)

The above implementation doesn't work. The relative_report_link_xpath would find other a (link) element which is not the sibling of the clicked span at all.

I'm using Selenium with Firefox/Python.

Comment: If I sumarize your question, you want to click on the first link with text as **Cases Report** amongs the reports which are marked as **Ready to download**. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, and more, I will use the more text in the span with "Ready to download" to select/filter the desired "Case Report". Thanks!

Comment: Can you update the question with what other `more text in the span` are expected?

Comment: Add the future logic requirements of using the timestamp information to select the span, then via the span to select its sibling link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using xpath:

```
span_xpath = '//span[contains(., "Ready to download")]' 
# . stands for text in the current node regardless of in bold or not

span_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(span_xpath)
# There might be multiple such links and spans
# I will have logic to select the desired one 
# based on the timestamp in the span. 
# For brevity, I just hard code the selection for now:

found_index = 0

report_link_xpath = \
'//span[contains(., "Ready to download")]//preceding-sibling::a[contains(@href, "/reports/")]' + \
'[' + str(found_index + 1) + ']'
# '//span[contains(., "Ready to download")]//preceding-sibling::a[contains(@href, "/reports/")][1]'

driver.find_element_by_xpath(report_link_xpath).click()
```

It works as expected.

The moral of the story is that Selenium provides the minimum wrapper on top of xpath as far as web element location is concerned, all operations should be done via xpath.

Comment: A quick solution by using xpath:  `//td[span[contains(., "Ready to download")]]/a`, you can directly get the `case report` link